# Why are all the correct axis's are blocked on my follow path?

Tags: axis

[image]

why the only time my character is in right position it is on a blocked axis? I have tried changing the offset. I have tried every combination of forward and up. I have tried unfollowing the curve and following it. My goal here is to make him walk across the path. I haven't made the walking animation yet but I figured I would do this first. Is that the right way to go about it? Because I just wanted to make a walk loop and didn't want to have to animate across the whole road.

Comment: the best help we can give is, if you provide your blend file....

Comment: here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-_DwS42nHfwJwyg7Vki2tQe3uNrv7mMJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The forward axis and the up axis can not be .... the same axis or [-axis].  So your picture could be improved by showing two legal axis.  The red color is showing modifier is inactivated with illegal combination of two entries.  What you call [correct] in the title has no meaning for Blender.  It will help you to drop that notion.

Comment: Hi Ricky, please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to show your blend file. and if you provide another link, it should at least not be with "request access". Thanks.

Comment: chris im sorry this took so long but that blender site wont take my file because its too big. Here is a dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxxcod3102tpixx/Road%20Scene%20Project%20File.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

1. select your armature
2. apply all transforms
3. object -> set origin to geometry
4. move your armature to the beginning of your path
5. armature -> follow path -> change settings to this:

[image]

6. and you get this:

[image]

Comment: when i do this this is the result i get. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7vhw1di5nmgesy4/2021-01-20%2006-35-43.mp4?dl=0

Comment: ok, provide your corrected blend file...i'll check it out

Comment: here is the new one. https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxxcod3102tpixx/Road%20Scene%20Project%20File.blend?dl=0 thank you so much